# Java crashes with Java was started but returned exit code=1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance

I use eclipse for android development.

Sometimes, if Google Chrome is running, it crashes and Eclipse also.

And I get message Java was started but returned exit code=1.
Full message is in print screen. 
[image]

and my eclipse.ini :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: increase the heap size available to Eclipse https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: It looks odd to me that you're pointing to a dll for your JVM (-vm arg). It might be allowed but read through this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Comment: @Rikki try changing the path of your `jvm.dll` file to `../bin/j9vm/jvm.dll` or `../bin/default/jvm.dll` or `../bin/classic/jvm.dll`

Answer (score 0):

If your JDK version is 32bit then download Eclipse or STS of 32 bit.
If your JDK version is 64bit then download Eclipse or STS of 64 bit.This worked for me